# What is the format for writing hypotheses in which there is both a moderator and a mediator?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design

I am designing a 2x2 factorial experiment. I know that there should be at least 3 hypotheses: one for each main effect and one for the interaction. However, I am also testing for a mediator. What should the hypothesis for the mediator be?

I want to investigate under what conditions the presence or absence of providing coaching improves performance versus when it does not.

My variables are as follows:

```
Two Independent Variables
 IV1 Coaching – 2 Levels
  IV1a Provided
  IV1b Not Provided

 IV2 Task Difficulty – 2 Levels – This is the moderator variable
  IV2a Hard motor skills task
  IV2b Easy motor skills task

 DV – Motor performance score (completions minus mistakes)
 Mediator Variable – Level of perceived self-efficacy (measured after the intervention)
```

What should the hypotheses for the interaction and the mediator be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "hypothesis", you mean "null hypothesis".

There isn't a general answer to your question because there is no unique model of mediation. Various notions of mediation have been proposed and so have various means of statistically investigating it. By contrast, it's easy to tell what the null hypotheses should be for testing the main effects and the moderator (i.e., interaction) because these things correspond directly to parameters of a linear model.